# EF Core 3.0 additional fileds mapping and updating

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

guys.

I have a problem with additional fields mapping and updating.

Let's have simple class

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string SameField { get; set; }
    public AuxClass AuxClass { get; set; }    
}

public class AuxClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string? AuxField { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
...
DbSet<User> UserDb { get; set; }
```

I expect that request like this

```
var tst = context.UserDb.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

returns object like this:

```
{
    Id = "AD8E1461-D6E8-4A04-8CFE-08D74FED1A72",
    SameField = "lala",
    AuxClass = null
}
```

But I get

```
{
    Id = "AD8E1461-D6E8-4A04-8CFE-08D74FED1A72",
    SameField = "lala",
    AuxClass = 
    {
        Id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        AuxField = null,
        UserId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        User = null
    }
}
```

So, first question - why? Second question - how to configure context do not to create object like this through requests?

And third question.

Suppose I have object of class User like this:

```
{
    Id = "AD8E1461-D6E8-4A04-8CFE-08D74FED1A72",
    SameField = "lala",
    AuxClass = 
    {
        Id = "AD8E1461-D6E8-4A04-8CFE-08D74FED1A83",
        AuxField = "lalala",
        UserId = "AD8E1461-D6E8-4A04-8CFE-08D74FED1A72",
        User = User
    }
}
```

I make a request `var tst = context.UserDb.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync();`, so, I have part of the object from Database and make changes:

```
{
    Id = "AD8E1461-D6E8-4A04-8CFE-08D74FED1A72",
    SameField = "lala12345",
    AuxClass = null
}
```

I want to update this object in the Database. I want to write the code like this

```
context.UserDb.Update(tst);
await context.SaveChangesAsync(true);
```

without erasing `AuxClass` field in the object stored in the Database. How's it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You should define the relation members as virtual and all problem solved :

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string SameField { get; set; }
    public virtual AuxClass AuxClass { get; set; }    
}

public class AuxClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string? AuxField { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```